# Duplicate each line in a text file

Tags: duplicates, line, txt

I would like to dupliacte lines in a folder with multiples txt files, including the blank lines. A batch command would be ideal or python drag&drop script.
Here is an example. (x being blank line)

```
Alfred
x
Britney
```

And I need it like this.

```
Alfred
Alfred
x
x
Britney
Britney
```

As you can see, each line is doubled even the lines where there are no texts.
How can that be done please ?

Comment: Please don't shout in all caps.

Comment: Read a line from the input, write the line twice, repeat.

Comment: Soory for caps, thanks for fixing it. Olaf, I know how to create batch files but nothing more. Would it be possible to have the proper code please ?

Answer (score 0):

I don't know about any ready made "batch command", but existing (Unix) tools can be used easily, e.g. [sed](https://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man1/sed.1p.html)

```
sed -e p /path/to/text/file.txt
```

or maybe [awk](https://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man1/awk.1p.html)

```
awk '{print; print;}' /path/to/text/file.txt
```

or Python (I'm no Python expert :-)

```
import fileinput
for line in fileinput.input():
    print(line.rstrip())
    print(line.rstrip())
```